# Get values from chart using bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a website that contains an info about AppStore ranking history:

```
https://sensortower.com/ios/US/ketchapp/app/2048/840919914/category-rankings?selected_tab=charts&start_date=2019-10-30&end_date=2019-11-28&countries=US&category=6014&chart_type=free&device=iphone&hourly=false&date=2019-11-28
```

I am trying to find out how can I get values from the chart on this web-site. Here is HTML of one chart value:

```
<path fill="transparent" d="M 149 248 A 4 4 0 1 1 149.00399999933333 247.99999800000018 Z" opacity="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0"></path>
```

Actually I need the last value '247.9999...'
Here is how this chart looks like:

[image]

Here is a piece of code i've tried, but it doesn't return the values:

```
for a in soup.find_all("g",{"class":"highcharts-markers ... highcharts-series-hover"}):
    print(a)
```